# Why did Klaue want to lay low?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018

In *Black Panther (2018)*, Erik Killmonger disembarks the plane (after having saved Klaue) and asks Klaue:

> Erik: You always sell to the CIA?
>
> Klaue: I sell to the highest bidder. But don't you worry. When I get
>   back to Jo'burg...and I **lay low** for a bit, I'll make sure both you guys
>   get paid.

Why did Klaue want to lay low?

Comment: When you're "a black-market arms dealer gangster and international criminal" it's probably advisable to lay low for a bit whenever you go somewhere new just to make sure you're safe and secure in that area.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember that Wakanda has wanted to capture Klaue for a *long time*, meaning they never stopped looking for him. That's why we have [this exchange](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=black-panther) (emphasis mine)

> SHURI: You will never guess who just popped up on our radar.
>   A misidentified Wakandan artifact... was stolen yesterday from a British museum. We have learned Ulysses Klaue... plans to sell the vibranium
>   to an American buyer... in South Korea...tomorrow night.
>   T'CHALLA: **Klaue has escaped our pursuits for almost 30 years. Not capturing him is, perhaps, my father's greatest regret.** I wish to bring Klaue back here to stand trial.

Klaue just had a narrow escape from them, meaning he has to lay low or the Wakandans will send more people after him. As it turns out (pretty hefty spoiler)

> Erik Killmonger is really a Wakandan prince. He only rescued Klaue from T'Challa so he could kill him himself, turn him in for favor among the local Wakandans, and then use that to foment a rebellion so he could take over Wakanda